# How to disable copy/paste commands in the Windows edit control context menu?

Tags: winapi, contextmenu, clipboard, editcontrol

How can I disable those 3 standard cut/copy/paste commands in the context menu of the native Windows OS edit control?

[image]

I also need to disable the equivalent clipboard-related commands like CTRL+C/CTRL+V.

Is there a special edit control style or anything else we can use to disable all copy/paste operations with one easy setting?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it's the requirement of some end-users ;). In the general case, we also need to add our custom items to that default OS context menu.

Comment: Strange users! Probably easiest to replace the entire menu with your own.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, do you want me to implement all those specific commands like "Right to left Reading order" by myself??

Comment: I doubt your users want those, right?

Comment: This is folly.  What about apps that use a non-native GUI?  How about toolbar buttons?  There is no way to 100% identify and disable these.

Comment: Smells like a misguided attempt to stop users pasting passwords.

Answer (score 14):

Typically, when a control displays a popup menu, a [`WM_INITPOPUPMENU`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646347.aspx) message is generated which "*allows an application to modify the menu before it is displayed, without changing the entire menu.*"

Unfortunately, a standard Win32 Edit control **does not generate that message** for its default popup menu, as confirmed in a November 2000 article of MSDN Magazine (the link on MSDN itself is dead, but this link is from the [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org)):

[MSDN Magazine, November 2000, C++ Q&A](https://web.archive.org/web/20121006084706/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301425.aspx):

> Q: Why isn't a WM_INITMENUPOPUP message generated when you right-click an edit control?
>
> A: I can't tell you why there isn't one, but I can **confirm it's true ... edit controls don't send WM_INITMENUPOPUP**. The edit control must be calling TrackPopupMenu with a null HWND handle and/or TPM_NONOTIFY, which tells the menu not to send notifications. It's possible (and again I'm only guessing) that the authors were trying to improve performance by reducing message traffic ... In any case, suppose you want to add your own menu items to the edit control context menu. How do you do it? Alas, you have no choice but to **reinvent the wheel**

So the only option available is to subclass the edit control and handle the [`WM_CONTEXTMENU`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647592.aspx) message instead, creating and displaying your own custom popup menu as needed.  Which means you have to manually duplicate the functionality of any standard menu items that you want to appear in your custom menu.

**Update**: there is a way to access and modify the edit control's standard popup menu after all (I just tested it and it worked).  TecMan provided a link to a [VBForums discussion](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?776385-RESOLVED-Modify-right-click-context-menu-in-standard-controls) that talks about it, however it gets a few details wrong.  I got the correct details from a [PureBasic forum discussion](http://www.purebasic.fr/english/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=60970).

The correct approach is as follows:

1. subclass the edit control to intercept the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message.  Either [`SetWindowSubClass()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) or [`SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) can be used, though [the first is preferred](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx).
2. when the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message is received, call [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) to install a thread-local hook (use 0 for the `hMod` parameter and `GetCurrentThreadId()` for the `dwThreadId` parameter).  Either a `WH_CBT` or `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook can be used.  Then dispatch `WM_CONTENTMENU` to the default message handler via [`DefSubclassProc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776403.aspx) or [`CallWindowProc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633571.aspx) to invoke the standard popup menu.
3. inside the hook procedure, when a `HCBT_CREATEWND` (`WH_CBT` hook) or `WM_CREATE` (`WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook) notification is received, pass the provided `HWND` to [`GetClassName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582.aspx).  If the class name is `#32768` (the standard window class name for menus, as [documented on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574.aspx#system)), **post** (very important!) a custom window message using [`PostMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx), specifying the menu window's `HWND` in the message's `WPARAM` or `LPARAM` parameter, to *any* `HWND` that you control, such as your main window, or even the edit control itself (since it is already subclassed). You will need the menu's `HWND` in the next step. You can optionally now uninstall the hook at this time, or wait for `DefSubclassProc()`/`CallWindowProc()` to exit (it will exit after the menu has been dismissed).  You need to use `PostMessage()` because the menu window has not created its `HMENU` yet at this time.  `PostMessage()` delays the next step until after the `HMENU` is ready.
4. when the custom window message is received, **send** a [`MN_GETMENU`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632613.aspx) message via [`SendMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) to the menu's `HWND` that you obtained from the hook.  You now have the menu's `HMENU` and can do whatever you want with it.
5. to disable the `Cut`, `Copy`, and `Paste` menu items, call [`EnableMenuItem()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647636.aspx).  Their menu item identifiers are the same values as the `WM_CUT`, `WM_COPY` and `WM_PASTE` messages, respectively (this is not documented by Microsoft, but is consistent across Windows versions).

**Update**: I just found a much simpler solution (which also worked when I tested it).

1. subclass the edit control to intercept `WM_CONTEXTMENU`, as described above.
2. when the message is received, call [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx) to install a thread-local event hook (set the `hmodWinEventProc` parameter to 0, the `idProcess` parameter to `GetCurrentProcessId()`, the `idThread` parameter to `GetCurrentThreadId()`, and the `dwFlags` parameter to 0 - not `WINEVENT_INCONTEXT`!).  Set the `eventMin` and `eventMax` parameters both to `EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART` so that it is the only event you receive.  Then dispatch the message to the default handler to invoke the popup menu.
3. when your event callback is called, the menu has already been fully initialized, so you can send the `MN_GETMENU` message to the provided `HWND`, which will be the menu's window (the callback's `idObject` parameter will be `OBJID_CLIENT` and the `idChild` parameter will be 0).
4. manipulate the `HMENU` as needed.
5. unhook the event hook when done using it, as described above.

---

As you can see here, this does work.

Before modifying the menu:

[image: before modifying the menu]

After disabling the menu items:

[image: Disabling the menu items]

Even deleting the menu items:

[image: Deleting the menu items]

Comment: See my answer with the link to vbforums.com. Perhaps, you know a better and/or documented way to retrieve the handle of the edit control's context menu?

Comment: @TecMan: one documented way to get a window's popup menu is the `MN_GETMENU` message. The trick is to get the popup menu's `HWND` so you can then get its `HMENU`. Hooking is the only way to do that.  However, the details provided in the VBForums link you provided are a little wrong. I have updated my answer with the correct details.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: your solution doesn't work for me because calling `DefSubclassProc`/`CallWindowProc` makes the context menu open but also the script STOP until next click. Thus only after the menu is closed there are calls to manipulate it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Salvador: I can't answer that without seeing your actual code.  But as I stated in my answer, I tested both hook approaches that I described, and they work fine for me. The technique determines the popup menu's `HWND` and posts a delayed window message back to the app before the menu is displayed. The menu's modal message loop will then dispatch that message to the app, and the message handler can then retrieve the `HMENU` from the `HWND` and manipulate the menu **while** it is active.  I have added screenshots to prove this works.

Comment: After hard work I wrote a [C version of the second approach](https://gist.github.com/michelesalvador/4a26852657521298f1f8c95cca77cb03). This should be definitely chosen like answer.

Comment: Nice Remy. Method works well. How to remove this "Reconversion" menu? what menu ID does that have?

Comment: @amaninlove I have no idea what its menu ID is.  But you can use `GetMenuItemCount()` and `GetMenuItemInfo()` to enumerate the menu items until you find the item you are interested in, then you will have its ID (and index) with which to manipulate it as needed.

Comment: Its good solution Remy. However, deleting items in that way is a bit sloppy since the callback is called after the menu has already been displayed. So it flashes available then removed. Your solution 1 using **SetWindowsHookEx** will probably work better since it catches the menu on the creation rather than after it had been displayed to the user. Disabling is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave the options visible but lock the clipboard from usage.
If this solution suits you all you need to do is make a program that opens the clipboard by calling `OpenClipboard(NULL)`. In order to release the clipboard call `CloseClipboard()`.

Comment: Beware of unintended consequences.  Lots of applications count on the clipboard working as documented.  So locking the clipboard for long periods of time is going to cause conflicts, crashes, etc..  Apps that you don't even expect, like Remote Desktop, may misbehave.

Answer (score 0):

One approach (similar to hypmir's idea but not quite as intrusive) is to simply overwrite the clipboard with "DATA REMOVED BY TecMan" whenever it is updated.  You could do this as a registered clipboard viewer.
Open the clipboard, clear all formats, add CF_TEXT with the notice, close it.
I would use a short delay (maybe a timer callback) so that you make your update AFTER the first update has been processed by any other registered clipboard viewers on the system.
*Your mileage may vary.*
*Abusing the clipboard like this is never a good idea.*

Answer (score 0):

I found one interesting idea of how to get the handle of the edit control's context menu on vbforums.com:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?776385-RESOLVED-Modify-right-click-context-menu-in-standard-controls

It demonstrates how to add custom context menu items to the standard OS context menu. I think, this idea can be used to modify the menu too. Theoretically I need to enumerate the menu items and disable the items related to the copy/paste commands. The question is how to know whether a menu item is related to copy/paste? Getting the menu item text is a bad idea ;)

Another problem of that code is that it is based on some Windows features that are not documented. I've checked the solution, it still works in Windows 10, but who knows how the edit control context menu may be changed in the future updates of the OS...

Comment: Although that VBForum discussion does discuss a technique for getting a standard edit control's `HMENU`, some of the details are wrong.  I have updated my answer with the correct details.