# How to change the background color of a windows context menu using the winapi

Tags: vb.net, winapi, pinvoke, outlook-addin

I am currently trying to customize a context menu in Outlook. For the regulars I have had a series of issues which can be seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206131/positioning-of-a-menu-item-image-hbmpitem-of-a-menuiteminfo-in-a-context-menu) and [with this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039964/is-there-something-special-about-the-wndproc-messages-for-a-richedit20wpt-window)

I would like to adjust the background color a little.

```
        Dim hBrush As IntPtr = NativeMethodsEX.CreateSolidBrush(ColorTranslator.ToWin32(System.Drawing.Color.Red))                
        Dim mi As New NativeMethodsEX.MenuInfo

            With mi
                .cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(mi)
                .fMask = NativeMethodsEX.MIM_STYLE Or NativeMethodsEX.MIM_BACKGROUND Or NativeMethodsEX.MIM_APPLYTOSUBMENUS
                .dwStyle = NativeMethodsEX.MNS_NOCHECK
                .hbrBack = hBrush
            End With

            NativeMethodsEX.SetMenuInfo(aHwnd, mi)
```

This code however produces this;[image].

How can I also change the background of the left hand side or what even is the class name of that part of the window.  Also it has a border as well. What is its class name or how can I either remove it or change it?

Comment: You will have to draw the entire menu as a custom drawn menu.

Comment: The entire menu and functionality or can i intercept a message at some point in time when the window itself is being created?

Comment: Probably not going to be viable in an addin. Give it up.

Comment: What happens when the user has chosen red as their menu text color? Your menus are completely unreadable, a show-stopper bug. Don't do this. Let the operating system control the theme, where it is customizable by the user.

Comment: This is an example for the question. I wanted it to be clear what the problem was.  I would be choosing a color that matches other menus in the application.  These seem to be "system" menus whereas some of the other menus with richer content and allow customization have a slightly different color.

Comment: so a simple link to an example of doing what I want to do would be fine.  @David - I hear you and I am almost there but not giving up just yet.

Comment: That's a quite different definition of the word "almost" from the one I know

Comment: Well as you can see I have already hacked the Outlook window structure to find the right windows, built a wndproc, intercept message for the context menu, add text/image and intercept the resulting message. I now just would like it to look nice.  It Christmas, Im doing this as a hobby not a job, give me some homework / reading David :-)